# Copying from one database from another database in Android with Sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to copy some columns from a table in database A into a table in database B. I use the following code but it prints error message "OldDB.ACC table does not exist". How should I correct it? Thanks!

and by the way, I put database B (OldDB) into DDMS/data/data/project name/databases

Thanks!!

```
public class DB {


private static final String TAG = "NotesDbAdapter";
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_ACC = "create table ACC "
        + "(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "Phone text, Name text, " + "MemID text, Smscode text, "
        + "RegDate text, Device text);";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Db";

private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_ACC = "ACC";

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private final Context mCtx;

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // create the database if there is no database
    // database stored inside the application
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_ACC);

        String str = "INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE_ACC + " (Phone) SELECT Phone FROM OldDB.ACC";
        db.execSQL(str);

    }
```

Comment: It is because "*OldDB.ACC table does not exist*"…

Comment: how can i make it exist? i have already put the file (OldDB) under the data/data/database folder....